# Multiple selection of two tables - multiple columns content

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I would like to combine them and as output to get different values, I will explain it shortly.

Table 1 - User list of channels: `user_id, channel_list`.

`User_id` is the nr. of the `user_id` and the `channel_list` contains the channels the user watched.

Lets say the channels are for example:

```
CNN, NBC, Eurosport, MTV and so on....
```

Table 2 - Channel sort - contains the columns - `channel`: `nbc, cnn, euro sport, MTV....` and column `Sort`, contains the sort of the channel- for example- `news, sport, entertainment` and so on... That is the character of the channel.

CNN, NBC are for example news, MTV is music...

The structure of table 1: `User_id` : `101` (example) and `channel_list`: `CNN, NBC, MTV`....(example)

I should pick up for each user from table 1 all the channels that are refer to as news from table 2 and to output, User nr. 1 watched lets say 2 channels with content news, but count them as 1 news, the same for all other channels with same content.

If a user watched 3 channels that are defined as sport channel in table 2, then I should define them as User nr. 1 - watched  sport but count it as one time sport channel, no matter how many channels he watched with content sport.

Finally the global results should be similar to:

```
user 1 - sport, news, music
user 2 - news
user 3 - music
```

That I should do for all user list, means the output should result all users and there topics of channels.

If it still isn't clear enough, then I will be happy to response for further questions.

Table 2:

columns: `user_id`, `date`, `Day(year)`, `channel_list`

```
"1006","2011-10-24","24","ProSieben,ZDF"
"1007","2011-06-24","24","9Live,DSF,Eurosport,ZDF"
"1008","2011-10-31","31","RTL,ZDF"
"101","2011-06-24","24","RTL,RTL2,ZDF"
"1010","2011-07-29","29","3sat,ZDF"
"1011","2011-07-14","14","KabelEins,ProSieben,SAT1,ZDF"
"1012","2011-04-29","29","DasErste,N24,NTV,RTL,SAT1,VOX,ZDF"
"1013","2011-05-18","18","KIKA,ProSieben,RegioTV,ZDF"
"1014","2011-09-07","7","DSF,ZDF"
```

Table 1:

columns: `channel`, `sort of channel`

```
HSE24, Extra shopping
KIKA, children
Viva, children
DeluxeMusic, music
MTV, music 
NDR, regional
CNN, news
OnTV, news
BloombergTVEurope, news
BBCWorldNews, news
EuroNews, news
NTV, news
```

And I have tried this:

```
  SELECT p.user_id, 
         s.sort 
    FROM table2 p 
    JOIN table1 s 
      ON s.channel = GROUP_CONCAT(p.channel_list) 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: post whatever you have tried

Comment: post the sql query u have tried

Comment: select  p.user_id, s.sort from table2  p join  table1  s on s.channel = GROUP_CONCAT(p.channel_list)

group by user_id

Comment: I tryed this query, but it outputs empty list. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would like to suggest you to change your table structure from `channel_list` to `channel_id` as an `INT` field and house each entry as a single entry like this:

```
1006,"2011-10-24",24,13
1006,"2011-10-24",24,14
1007,"2011-06-24",24,15
1007,"2011-06-24",24,16
1007,"2011-06-24",24,17
1007,"2011-06-24",24,14
1008,"2011-10-31",31,18
1008,"2011-10-31",31,14
101,"2011-06-24",24,18
101,"2011-06-24",24,19
101,"2011-06-24",24,14
1010,"2011-07-29",29,14
1010,"2011-07-29",29,20
```

Then you can easily retrieve the data as such:

```
  SELECT p.user_id, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.sort) AS `sort`
    FROM table2 p 
    JOIN table1 s 
      ON s.id = p.channel_id
GROUP BY user_id
```

With `DISTINCT` you won't get repeated `sort` and by having each channel on its own row and unique id, you can easily relation both table rather than having an aggregated list into a single row, which doesn't really make sense since you're using a database.

[**Here is a live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afe95/2)